# Laravel 8.x - 403 Invalid Signature while running behind Cloudflare and Load Balancer

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, cloudflare

I am running a Laravel 8.x app behind a Nginx load balancer. I have 2 app servers where the laravel app resides and another server for mysql database.

The problem here is when my app is proxied on Cloudflare (orange cloud), the user gets `403 | Invalid Signature` error when verifying their email address.

I used [laravel-cloudflare](https://github.com/monicahq/laravel-cloudflare) package and replace `use Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies as Middleware;` with `use Monicahq\Cloudflare\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies as Middleware` on `app/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php` so I can add Cloudflare's IP address as trusted proxy.

I also address the IP address of my load balancer on `protected $proxies = ['lb-ip-address'];`.

My app was able to get the correct user IP address and also correct generated URL.

There's no problem verifying email address if I turn off Cloudflare proxy and use letsencrypt ssl on my load balancer. But if Cloudflare proxy is on our user received 403 Invalid signature error.

Comment: Have you fixed this issue yet?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by changing the APP_URL to match the domain the request is coming in on, obviously you need to config:cache etc.

Answer (score 0):

if you use load balance you must force https with `URL::forceScheme('https');`.
Laravel include all URL whene add the sign but the real url in the pod is in http.

I resolved in this mode:

```php
$signed = URL::signedRoute(
    'ROUTE_NAME', // for example /foo/bar
    [
        'PARAM' => 'VALUE',
    ],
    false
); // generate: /foo/bar/VALUE?signed=hash
$ur = URL::to($signed); // generate: https://www.example.com/foo/bar/VALUE?signed=hash
};
```

in the route file:

```php
Route::middleware('signed:relative')->get(
    'foo/bar/{PARAM}',
    [Controller::class, 'function']
)->name('ROUTE_NAME');
```